# Error spliting an std::index_sequence

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, std

I'm trying to split an `index_sequence` into two halves. For that, I generate an `index_sequence` with the lower half and use it to skip the leading elements on the full `index_sequence`. The following is a minimal test case that represents what I'm trying to achieve:

```
template <int ...I>
struct index_sequence {};

template <int ...I, int ...J>
void foo(index_sequence<I...>, index_sequence<I..., J...>)
{}

int main()
{
    foo(index_sequence<0>{}, index_sequence<0, 1>{});
}
```

I've tried this with the latest versions of *Clang*, *GCC* and *MSVC*, and they all fail to deduce `J...`. Is this allowed by the standard? If not, why and what would be a good way to achieve my intent?

Comment: You could make a `template<int... I> struct bar { template<int... J> void foo(index_sequence<I..., J...>); };`, or use `template <int ...I, int ...J>
void foo(index_sequence<I...>, index_sequence<J...>)
{}` and split the seq in another step.

Comment: Are your sequences always [0,N] and [0,N+x]? Because it would be *much* simpler to generate an `index_sequence` with [N,N+x] in the first place than to perform a general prefix-stripping or set difference.

Comment: @Casey: No. Shifting a sequence is considerably easy. This question is about the general case where you have half an `index_sequence` and you need to get the remaining half in _O(1)_ instantiations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **14.8.2.5/9** ... If the template argument list of `P` contains a pack expansion that is not the last template argument, the entire template argument list is a non-deduced context...

Thus, when comparing `index_sequence<I..., J...>` with `index_sequence<0, 1>{}`, neither `I...` nor `J...` can be deduced.

Comment: *"neither `I...` nor `J...` can be deduced"* from the second argument. `I` can still be deduced from the first argument.

Comment: @DyP: But the quote says the entire argument list is a non-deduced context. Which means `J` won't be deduced even if `I` can

Comment: @AndyProwl Indeed. I'm being a bit nit-picky here ;)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to interpret that paragraph. Obviously `template <int ...I, int ...J>
void foo(index_sequence<I...>, index_sequence<J...>)` works and both `I` and `J` are deduced correctly... would you care to elaborate how that paragraph applies to this variation?

Comment: @K-ballo Yeah, the context is missing. That quote is about a single parameter `P` of a function template, where the parameter type has a template argument list.

Comment: @DyP: Ah, I see, makes sense... This seems to imply that a helper struct is the only way to provide the first half of the list explicitly and still be able to specialize on it to get the actual indices.

Answer (score 9):

If what you want is to split a `std::index_sequence` instead of removing the common prefix of two `std::index_sequence`s, I think you can benefit from an implementation of `slice` and using it to split a `std::index_sequence` into pieces.

I'm going to omit the implementation of `std::index_sequence` and friends, since you can refer to the paper, [N3658](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3658.html), and a sample implementation [here](https://gitorious.org/redistd/integer_seq/?p=redistd:integer_seq.git;a=blob;f=integer_seq.h;hb=HEAD).

#### make_index_range

To implement `slice`, we'll use a helper called `make_integer_range`. We want a `std::index_sequence` generator which gives us [Begin, End) instead of [0, End). Leveraging `std::make_integer_sequence`, we get:

```
template <typename T, typename Seq, T Begin>
struct make_integer_range_impl;

template <typename T, T... Ints, T Begin>
struct make_integer_range_impl<T, std::integer_sequence<T, Ints...>, Begin> {
  using type = std::integer_sequence<T, Begin + Ints...>;
};

/* Similar to std::make_integer_sequence<>, except it goes from [Begin, End)
   instead of [0, End). */
template <typename T, T Begin, T End>
using make_integer_range = typename make_integer_range_impl<
    T, std::make_integer_sequence<T, End - Begin>, Begin>::type;

/* Similar to std::make_index_sequence<>, except it goes from [Begin, End)
   instead of [0, End). */
template <std::size_t Begin, std::size_t End>
using make_index_range = make_integer_range<std::size_t, Begin, End>;
```

#### slice

Since we don't have a `std::get`-like functionality for `std::index_sequence` or a variadic template pack, we just build a temporary `std::array` to get us `std::get`. Then explode the array with only the slice we want.

```
template <std::size_t... Indices, std::size_t... I>
constexpr decltype(auto) slice_impl(
      std::index_sequence<Indices...>,
      std::index_sequence<I...>) {
  using Array = std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(Indices)>;
  return std::index_sequence<std::get<I>(Array{{Indices...}})...>();
}

template <std::size_t Begin, std::size_t End, std::size_t... Indices>
constexpr decltype(auto) slice(std::index_sequence<Indices...> idx_seq) {
  return slice_impl(idx_seq, make_index_range<Begin, End>());
}
```

#### split_at

One example of using the `slice` we just built is to write a `split_at` function. We specify the index at which we want to split the `std::index_sequence`, and return a pair of `std::index_sequence`s split at the given index.

```
template <std::size_t At, std::size_t... Indices>
constexpr decltype(auto) split_at(index_sequence<Indices...> idx_seq) {
    return std::make_pair(slice<0, At>(idx_seq), 
                          slice<At, sizeof...(Indices)>(idx_seq));
}
```

#### Examples of `split_at`:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<
                decltype(split_at<2>(index_sequence<1, 4, 2>())),
                std::pair<index_sequence<1, 4>, index_sequence<2>>>(), "");

static_assert(std::is_same<
                decltype(split_at<1>(index_sequence<1, 4, 2, 3>())),
                std::pair<index_sequence<1>, index_sequence<4, 2, 3>>>(), "");
```

Comment: Interesting idea that of turning an `std::index_sequence` into an `std::array` to then use it like an `std::tuple`.

Comment: @mpark What's `std::common_type` here for?

Comment: @LogicStuff: Haha that was me being overly fancy and using `std::common_type` with a single type as "identity". `std::common_type` actually can't be used as an "identity" so I've edited the answer.

Comment: I'm already using your code and it seems to work without anything special. Just `struct make_integer_range_impl<T, std::integer_sequence<T, Ints...>, Begin> : std::integer_sequence<T, (Begin + Ints)...> {};`

Comment: Is it possible to implement `slice` and `slice_impl` using C++11?

Comment: @GregvonWinckel: yeah, you'd have to write your own `index_sequence` but with that I think you'd be fine? I noticed that the sample implementation link is broken so I've fixed that

Answer (score 2):

To get suffix, you may use something like:

```
template<int ... I> struct get_suffix_helper {
    template<int ... J> static index_sequence<J...> foo(index_sequence<I..., J...>);
};

template<typename T1, typename T2> struct get_suffix;

template<int ... Is1, int ... Is2>
struct get_suffix<index_sequence<Is1...>, index_sequence<Is2...>> :
    public decltype(get_suffix_helper<Is1...>::foo(std::declval<index_sequence<Is2...>>())) {};

static_assert(std::is_base_of<index_sequence<>,
                              get_suffix<index_sequence<1, 2>,
                                         index_sequence<1, 2>>>::value, "error");

static_assert(std::is_base_of<index_sequence<42>,
                              get_suffix<index_sequence<1, 2>,
                                         index_sequence<1, 2, 42>>>::value, "error");
```

Or, with some error check:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> struct get_suffix;

template<int ...Is>
struct get_suffix<index_sequence<>, index_sequence<Is...>>
{
    typedef index_sequence<Is...> type;
    static const bool valid = true;
};

template<int ...Is>
struct get_suffix<index_sequence<Is...>, index_sequence<>>
{
    typedef void type;
    static const bool valid = false;
};

template<>
struct get_suffix<index_sequence<>, index_sequence<>>
{
    typedef index_sequence<> type;
    static const bool valid = true;
};

template<int N, int ...Is, int... Js>
struct get_suffix<index_sequence<N, Is...>, index_sequence<N, Js...>>
{
    typedef typename get_suffix<index_sequence<Is...>, index_sequence<Js...>>::type type;
    static const bool valid = get_suffix<index_sequence<Is...>, index_sequence<Js...>>::valid;
};

template<int N1, int N2, int ...Is, int... Js>
struct get_suffix<index_sequence<N1, Is...>, index_sequence<N2, Js...>>
{
    typedef void type;
    static const bool valid = false;
};

static_assert(std::is_same<index_sequence<>,
                           get_suffix<index_sequence<1, 2>,
                                      index_sequence<1, 2>>::type>::value, "error");

static_assert(!get_suffix<index_sequence<1, 2, 42>, index_sequence<1, 2>>::valid, "error");
static_assert(!get_suffix<index_sequence<0, 2, 1>, index_sequence<0, 1, 2>>::valid, "error");

static_assert(std::is_same<index_sequence<42>,
                           get_suffix<index_sequence<1, 2>,
                                      index_sequence<1, 2, 42>>::type>::value, "error");
```

Comment: The number of instantiations in a recursive solution is of linear complexity, which tends to perform poorly at compile time.

Comment: @K-ballo: Added an improved version (but without error checking)

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but a workaround: recursively trim off the leading elements a la:

```
template <typename, typename> struct remove_prefix;

template <std::size_t... I>
struct remove_prefix<index_sequence<>, index_sequence<I...>> {
  using type = index_sequence<I...>;
};

template <std::size_t First, std::size_t... I, std::size_t... J>
struct remove_prefix<index_sequence<First, I...>,
                     index_sequence<First, J...>> {
  using type = typename remove_prefix<index_sequence<I...>,
                                      index_sequence<J...>>::type;
};
```

[Demo at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85f7c293760c9fc9).

Comment: The number of instantiations in a recursive solution is of linear complexity, which tends to perform poorly at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to split an index_sequence into a head and tail at a particular point and this was the implementation that I came up with:

```
template<size_t N, typename Lseq, typename Rseq>
struct split_sequence_impl;

template<size_t N, size_t L1, size_t...Ls, size_t...Rs>
struct split_sequence_impl<N,index_sequence<L1,Ls...>,index_sequence<Rs...>>  { 
  using next = split_sequence_impl<N-1,index_sequence<Ls...>,index_sequence<Rs...,L1>>;
  using head = typename next::head;
  using tail = typename next::tail;
};

template<size_t L1, size_t...Ls, size_t...Rs>
struct split_sequence_impl<0,index_sequence<L1,Ls...>,index_sequence<Rs...>> {
  using tail = index_sequence<Ls...>;
  using head = index_sequence<Rs...,L1>;
};

template<typename seq, size_t N> 
using split_sequence = split_sequence_impl<N-1,seq,empty_sequence>;

template<typename seq, size_t N>
using sequence_head_t = typename split_sequence<seq,N>::head;

template<typename seq, size_t N>
using sequence_tail_t = typename split_sequence<seq,N>::tail;
```